# Calling a Func From a Task

Tags: c#, task, func

I am writing a custom reporting tool that allows the users to possibly create some very broad queries. I wanted to add a timeout to this so if the user creates something that will end up running quite long, the entire system won't stall. I came up with this:

```
public List<List<SimpleDisplayField>> FindReport(int reportId)
    {
        var report = GetReportById(reportId);

        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
        int timeOut = 20000; // 2 seconds

        if (report.BidType == "LOB")
        {
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FindLOBReport(report), token);
            if (!task.Wait(timeOut, token))
            {
                throw new Exception("Report ran for more than 10 seconds.. run again or add more filters.");  
            }
            return task.Result;
        }
        else
        {
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FindFWOReport(report), token);
            if (!task.Wait(timeOut, token))
            {
                throw new Exception("Report ran for more than 10 seconds.. run again or add more filters.");
            }
            return task.Result;
        }
    }
```

Which is fine but I wanted to refactor it into something like this instead, using Func's so I could pass either the FindLOBReport or FindFWOReport as a parameter:

```
public List<List<SimpleDisplayField>> FindReport(int reportId)
    {
        var report = GetReportById(reportId);

        if (report.BidType == "LOB")
        {
            return RunReport(FindLOBReport(report));
        }
        else
        {
            return RunReport(FindFWOReport(report));
        }
    }

    private List<List<SimpleDisplayField>> RunReport(Func<CustomReport, List<List<SimpleDisplayField>>> method)
    {
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
        int timeOut = 20000; // 2 seconds

        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => method, token);
        if (!task.Wait(timeOut, token))
        {
            throw new Exception("Report ran for more than 10 seconds.. run again or add more filters.");
        }

        return task.Result;
    }
```

However, task.Result is a 'Func' return type, whereas I just want task.Result to return my List>. Are there any ways to remedy this?

Comment: What does `FindLOBReport` do? Does it calls database? Btw you're not calling the `method`.

Comment: Your function takes a `CustomReport` - what parameter do you expect it to receive? What is the signature of `FindLOBReport`? I suspect you're getting a bit confused about the difference between providing a method group for delegate conversion, and *calling* a method.

Comment: @JonSkeet your suspicion is most likely correct. FindLOBReport accepts a CustomReport and returns a 2D List.

Comment: @logan_gabriel: Right, so it sounds like you might want to call `RunReport(FindLOBReport)` - but `RunReport` would need to accept the `report` as well. Or you could call `RunReport(() => FindLOBReport(report))` and change the parameter of `RunReport` to `Func<List<List<SimpleDisplayField>>>`

Comment: You're executing a task and synchronously waiting on it. Do you really need the task?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I believe so unless you have alternatives.. I don't want to continue running the task if it's been running more than x seconds

Comment: Are you actually canceling the query or simply discarding it? Also, is a query timing out something you expect to happen as part of normal execution flow?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov so because the reporting tool allows the user to create any kind of query, they could potentially query and join on many different objects and retrieve back a huge amount of results. Also, I do a fair amount of reflection in those calls, so it has the potential to run for a long time. I simply want to stop running that method after a designated time.

Comment: Well, first of all, you're still executing the query. You're only discarding the result, the query itself is still being executed. Second of all, if you're doing some heavy lifting and expect long execution time, don't use exceptions. Exceptions are for, well, exceptional cases. Instead, use some sort of structed result which says the query failed.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I see. I am open to suggestions of course. I searched "implement a timeout" on stack overflow and this approach was popular.

Comment: Use `SqlCommand.Timeout` property which will cancel your query after the given timeout. Currently your query will run till its default timeout is done.

Comment: I'll try to post something useful tomorrow when i'm infront of my computer.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov thanks for the help. I answered this question with what I currently have now, if you could verify and take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `RunReport` method, you're not actually calling the `method` Func. You're retuning the `method` delegate. That is why the `Task.Result` is inferred as `Func<>`.

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => method, token);
```

Above code is equal to

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                 {
                                    return method;
                                 }, token);
```

To execute it, you need to invoke it using method call syntax.

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => method(report), token);
```

To be able to do that, you need the report as parameter.

```
private List<List<SimpleDisplayField>> RunReport(Func<CustomReport, List<List<SimpleDisplayField>>> method,CustomReport report)
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
    int timeOut = 20000; // 2 seconds

    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => method(report), token);
    if (!task.Wait(timeOut, token))
    {
        throw new Exception("Report ran for more than 10 seconds.. run again or add more filters.");
    }

    return task.Result;
}
```

Then you can call it as

```
public List<List<SimpleDisplayField>> FindReport(int reportId)
{
    var report = GetReportById(reportId);
    return (report.BidType == "LOB")
           ? RunReport(FindLOBReport, report)
           : RunReport(FindFWOReport, report);
}
```

Also worth noting that your `Task` isn't cancelled. It will continue to run. It is a important thing to note. If your `FindLOBReport` method essentially calls Database and if that's what taking time --you're better off using `SqlCommand.Timeout` property. That will cancel the underlying operation.

Respecting the @YuvalItzchakov's comment. He says no point in waiting for the starting the Task and waiting for its completion synchronously. You should seriously look at [awaiting it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

Btw 20000 milliseconds is not 2 seconds. It is 20 seconds.

Comment: Waiting synchronously on a task after executing it? C'mon.. ;p

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov There are several problems in the approach :\ Stackoverflow post isn't enough for me. Did you notice the task runs still after the method is finished.

Comment: Yeah, see my question to the OP at the top. Couple of things he needs to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the feedback everyone. My solution now looks like this:

```
public List<List<SimpleDisplayField>> FindReport(int reportId)
    {
        var report = GetReportById(reportId);
        return (report.BidType == "LOB")
               ? RunReportAsync(FindLOBReport, report).Result
               : RunReportAsync(FindFWOReport, report).Result;
    }

    private async Task<List<List<SimpleDisplayField>>> RunReportAsync(Func<CustomReport, List<List<SimpleDisplayField>>> method, CustomReport report)
    {
        var task = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => method.DynamicInvoke(report));
        return (List<List<SimpleDisplayField>>)task;
    }
```

And in FindLOB/FWOReport I am using this to timeout the query:

```
 using (TRACSEntities db = new TRACSEntities())
            {
                db.Database.CommandTimeout = 60;
                var query = // and so on
            }
```